# When scraping from a webpage, the html isn't the same as when I inspect element?

Tags: java, python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I'm trying to web scrape this website: https://www.footballindex.co.uk/top-200

More specifically I want to scrape the name, buy price, sell price of every player.

This is my code I used to get the web html:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.footballindex.co.uk/top-200"
page = requests.get(URL)
Soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
print(Soup)
```

When I print out the html the information I'm looking for doesn't come out under a relevant variable like in the inspect element. It comes out in one long line of code as below. (I've cut it off but it does this for every player on the page).

```
 window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = {"tradingReducer":{"adjustedPrice":0,"isLoading":false},"playersReducer":{"players":[{"id":"phil-foden","name":"Phil Foden","rank":14,"country":"England","nationalTeam":null,"sector":"Midfielder","nationality":"England","team":"Manchester City","optimized_image":"phil-foden-g-t4.jpg","buyPrice":5.93,"sellPrice":5.87,"penceChange":0.12,"changePercent":2.05},{"id":"bruno-fernandes","name":"Bruno Fernandes",
```

I tried also using Selenium but it just gave me the data in the same place. From other posts I've read and info I've found it sounds like it's because the website uses Java to load the prices of players especially. On the page they're constantly updating every few seconds.

The code seems to be in JSON format. But I've been completely stumped as to how I can extract the information into python so I can capture each player and their relevant buy price.
I've tried using the find and find_all functions but every time it doesn't seem to extract any data.

Does anyone know what code I need to use to correctly extract the variables I want from the html?

Comment: HI hammer96, welcome to stack overflow ;-) When you inspect the page, you'll see the DOM as it's currently rendered - meaning all the dsynamic HTML added through JavaScript etc. is in there as well. That's not the case if you simply download the page source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My way around it - may not be the best - is to use selenium to make sure that a javascript loads all data and then pass this HTML to beautifulsoup to parse and use regex to match data needed. `time.sleep` is used to make sure that all data in Java is loaded. You can experiment with it and lower it as needed to speed up your script.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import re

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.set_window_size(700,900)

url = 'https://www.footballindex.co.uk/top-200'

browser.get(url)
time.sleep(4)

html = browser.execute_script('return document.documentElement.outerHTML')


all_html = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
root = all_html.find('div', {'class':'List__container___1xBmN'})

all_buy_prices= re.findall('(buy" type="button">)(\£\d+\.\d+)(</button>)', str(root))

buy_price= all_buy_prices
print('Buy prices:')
print(str(buy_price))

browser.quit()
```

This will get you main Div of the page with all data. Now, you can user REGEX to find some data you need.

```
<div class="List__container___1xBmN"><div class="List__containerBorder___nK1FG false"><div class="Header__header___1UCQ_ Header__top200___1a9En"><div>Name</div><div class=""><div class="Chevrons__container___1c4KD"><div class="Chevrons__title___yCmH6">Team</div><div class="Chevrons__chevrons___1ysGb"><div class="Chevrons__chevron___11hD7 false"></div><div class="Chevrons__chevron___11hD7 Chevrons__bottom___g1Tu6 false"></div></div></div></div><div class=""><div class="Chevrons__container___1c4KD"><div class="Chevrons__title___yCmH6 Chevrons__title__noCursor___W9MWN">Country</div></div></div><div class=""><div class="Chevrons__container___1c4KD Chevrons__centered___3WXrp"><div class="Chevrons__title___yCmH6">Position</div><div class="Chevrons__chevrons___1ysGb"><div class="Chevrons__chevron___11hD7 false"></div><div class="Chevrons__chevron___11hD7 Chevrons__bottom___g1Tu6 false"></div></div></div></div><div class=""><div class="Chevrons__container___1c4KD Chevrons__centered___3WXrp"><div class="Chevrons__title___yCmH6">24h</div><div class="Chevrons__chevrons___1ysGb"><div class="Chevrons__chevron___11hD7 Chevrons__active___2Pu9u"></div><div class="Chevrons__chevron___11hD7 Chevrons__bottom___g1Tu6 false"></div></div></div></div><div class=""><div class="Chevrons__container___1c4KD Chevrons__centered___3WXrp"><div class="Chevrons__title___yCmH6 Chevrons__title__noCursor___W9MWN">Watchlist</div></div></div><div class="bootstrap__dropdown___2TcPW Dropdown__dropdown___3P4JX"><button class="Dropdown__dropdown__button___9QeA8" type="button">Price inc. £<i class="bootstrap__glyphicon___17Rfb bootstrap__glyphicon-chevron-down___3xTUv"></i></button></div></div><div><div class="sc-bwzfXH gXUZUa"><div class="Pic__container___3KX2N Pic__container__threeColumns___1Zbax"><div class="Pic__container__rank___3rCJC">8</div><div class="Pic__hexagonContainer___3tlAo"><div class="HexagonContainer__hexagon___3lz4M Pic__container__celebImage___LfP-u"><div class="HexagonContainer__innerHexagon___DbA3c"><div class="HexagonContainer__coreHexagon___3HXiI"><img alt="Paul Pogba" class="HexagonImage__imageContents___ZSIfo HexagonImage__image___2jE99" src="https://img.footballindex.co.uk/paul-pogba-g-t9.jpg"/></div></div></div></div><div class="Pic__container__name___26P8X"><a href="/player/paul-pogba">P.Pogba</a><a class="Row__team___3CPAz" href="/club/Manchester_United">Manchester United</a></div></div><div class="Change__container___ZKCNS Change__container__positive___2mmVZ">£0.19</div><div class="BuyAndSellButtons__buttonContainer___3uLe5"><button class="Button__sell-background___Pu5NC Button__button___3_Ozh Button__tradingMedium___TOIwW Button__yellow-glow___20bvG SellButton__price___3omkd tradingMedium SellButton__default___2LgzG" id="sell" type="button">£7.92</button><button class="Button__buy-background___3wyrT Button__button___3_Ozh Button__tradingMedium___TOIwW Button__yellow-glow___20bvG BuyButton__price___1Ylr9 tradingMedium" id="buy" type="button">£8.06</button></div></div><div class="sc-bwzfXH gXUZUa"><div class="Pic__container___3KX2N Pic__container__threeColumns___1Zbax"><div class="Pic__container__rank___3rCJC">11</div><div class="Pic__hexagonContainer___3tlAo"><div class="HexagonContainer__hexagon___3lz4M Pic__container__celebImage___LfP-u"><div class="HexagonContainer__innerHexagon___DbA3c"><div class="HexagonContainer__coreHexagon___3HXiI"><img alt="Mason Greenwood" class="HexagonImage__imageContents___ZSIfo HexagonImage__image___2jE99" src="https://img.footballindex.co.uk/mason-greenwood-g-t6.jpg"/></div></div></div></div><div class="Pic__container__name___26P8X"><a href="/player/mason-greenwood">M.Greenwood</a><a class="Row__team___3CPAz" href="/club/Manchester_United">Manchester United</a></div></div><div class="Change__container___ZKCNS Change__container__positive___2mmVZ">£0.16</div><div class="BuyAndSellButtons__buttonContainer___3uLe5"><button class="Button__sell-background___Pu5NC Button__button___3_Ozh Button__tradingMedium___TOIwW Button__yellow-glow___20bvG SellButton__price___3omkd tradingMedium SellButton__default___2LgzG" id="sell" type="button">£6.24</button><button class="Button__buy-background___3wyrT Button__button___3_Ozh Button__tradingMedium___TOIwW Button__yellow-glow___20bvG BuyButton__price___1Ylr9 tradingMedium" id="buy" type="button">£6.33</button></div></div><div class="sc-bwzfXH gXUZUa"><div class="Pic__container___3KX2N Pic__container__threeColumns___1Zbax"><div class="Pic__container__rank___3rCJC">2</div><div class="Pic__hexagonContainer___3tlAo"><div class="HexagonContainer__hexagon___3lz4M Pic__container__celebImage___LfP-u"><div class="HexagonContainer__innerHexagon___DbA3c"><div class="HexagonContainer__coreHexagon___3HXiI"><img alt="Bruno Fernandes" class="HexagonImage__imageContents___ZSIfo HexagonImage__image___2jE99" src="https://img.footballindex.co.uk/bruno-fernandes-g-t2.jpg"/></div></div></div></div><div class="Pic__container__name___26P8X"><a href="/player/bruno-fernandes">B.Fernandes</a><a class="Row__team___3CPAz" href="/club/Manchester_United">Manchester United</a></div></div><div class="Change__container___ZKCNS Change__container__positive___2mmVZ">£0.09</div><div class="BuyAndSellButtons__buttonContainer___3uLe5"><button class="Button__sell-background___Pu5NC Button__button___3_Ozh Button__tradingMedium___TOIwW Button__yellow-glow___20bvG SellButton__price___3omkd tradingMedium SellButton__default___2LgzG" id="sell" type="button">£10.13</button><button class="Button__buy-background___3wyrT Button__button___3_Ozh Button__tradingMedium___TOIwW Button__yellow-glow___20bvG BuyButton__price___1Ylr9 tradingMedium" id="buy" type="button">£10.35</button></div></div><div class="sc-bwzfXH gXUZUa"><div class="Pic__container___3KX2N Pic__container__threeColumns___1Zbax"><div class="Pic__container__rank___3rCJC">132</div><div class="Pic__hexagonContainer___3tlAo"><div class="HexagonContainer__hexagon___3lz4M Pic__container__celebImage___LfP-u"><div class="HexagonContainer__innerHexagon___DbA3c"><div class="HexagonContainer__coreHexagon___3HXiI"><img alt="Rhian Brewster" class="HexagonImage__imageContents___ZSIfo HexagonImage__image___2jE99" src="https://img.footballindex.co.uk/rhian-brewster-g-t2.jpg"/></div></div></div></div><div class="Pic__container__name___26P8X"><a href="/player/rhian-brewster">R.Brewster</a><a class="Row__team___3CPAz" href="/club/Swansea_City">Swansea City</a></div></div><div class="Change__container___ZKCNS Change__container__positive___2mmVZ">£0.07</div><div class="BuyAndSellButtons__buttonContainer___3uLe5"><button class="Button__sell-background___Pu5NC Button__button___3_Ozh Button__tradingMedium___TOIwW Button__yellow-glow___20bvG SellButton__price___3omkd tradingMedium SellButton__default___2LgzG" id="sell" type="button">£1.99</button><button class="Button__buy-background___3wyrT Button__button___3_Ozh Button__tradingMedium___TOIwW Button__yellow-glow___20bvG BuyButton__price___1Ylr9 tradingMedium" id="buy" type="button">£2.07</button></div></div><div class="sc-bwzfXH gXUZUa"><div class="Pic__container___3KX2N Pic__container__threeColumns___1Zbax"><div class="Pic__container__rank___3rCJC">131</div><div class="Pic__hexagonContainer___3tlAo"><div class="HexagonContainer__hexagon___3lz4M Pic__container__celebImage___LfP-u"><div class="HexagonContainer__innerHexagon___DbA3c"><div class="HexagonContainer__coreHexagon___3HXiI"><img alt="Steven Bergwijn" class="HexagonImage__imageContents___ZSIfo HexagonImage__image___2jE99" src="https://img.footballindex.co.uk/steven-bergwijn-g-t3.jpg"/></div></div></div></div><div class="Pic__container__name___26P8X"><a href="/player/steven-bergwijn">S.Bergwijn</a><a class="Row__team___3CPAz" href="/club/Tottenham_Hotspur">Tottenham Hotspur</a></div></div><div class="Change__container___ZKCNS Change__container__positive___2mmVZ">£0.06</div><div class="BuyAndSellButtons__buttonContainer___3uLe5"><button class="Button__sell-background___Pu5NC Button__button___3_Ozh Button__tradingMedium___TOIwW Button__yellow-glow___20bvG SellButton__price___3omkd tradingMedium SellButton__default___2LgzG" id="sell" type="button">£1.96</button><button class="Button__buy-background___3wyrT Button__button___3_Ozh Button__tradingMedium___TOIwW Button__yellow-glow___20bvG BuyButton__price___1Ylr9 tradingMedium" id="buy" type="button">£2.08</button></div></div><div class="sc-bwzfXH gXUZUa"><div class="Pic__container___3KX2N Pic__container__threeColumns___1Zbax"><div class="Pic__container__rank___3rCJC">100</div><div class="Pic__hexagonContainer___3tlAo"><div class="HexagonContainer__hexagon___3lz4M Pic__container__celebImage___LfP-u"><div class="HexagonContainer__innerHexagon___DbA3c"><div class="HexagonContainer__coreHexagon___3HXiI"><img alt="Marco Asensio" class="HexagonImage__imageContents___ZSIfo HexagonImage__image___2jE99" src="https://img.footballindex.co.uk/marco-asensio-g-t5.jpg"/></div></div></div></div><div class="Pic__container__name___26P8X"><a href="/player/marco-asensio">M.Asensio</a><a class="Row__team___3CPAz" href="/club/Real_Madrid">Real Madrid</a></div></div><div class="Change__container___ZKCNS Change__container__positive___2mmVZ">£0.03</div><div class="BuyAndSellButtons__buttonContainer___3uLe5"><button class="Button__sell-background___Pu5NC Button__button___3_Ozh Button__tradingMedium___TOIwW Button__yellow-glow___20bvG SellButton__price___3omkd tradingMedium SellButton__default___2LgzG" id="sell" type="button">£2.18</button><button class="Button__buy-background___3wyrT Button__button___3_Ozh Button__tradingMedium___TOIwW Button__yellow-glow___20bvG BuyButton__price___1Ylr9 tradingMedium" id="buy" type="button">£2.26</button></div></div><div class="sc-bwzfXH gXUZUa"><div class="Pic__container___3KX2N Pic__container__threeColumns___1Zbax"><div class="Pic__container__rank___3rCJC">144</div><div class="Pic__hexagonContainer___3tlAo"><div class="HexagonContainer__hexagon___3lz4M Pic__container__celebImage___LfP-u"><div class="HexagonContainer__innerHexagon___DbA3c"><div class="HexagonContainer__coreHexagon___3HXiI"><img alt="Riccardo Orsolini" class="HexagonImage__imageContents___ZSIfo HexagonImage__image___2jE99" src="https://img.footballindex.co.uk/riccardo-orsolini-g-t2.jpg"/></div></div></div></div><div class="Pic__container__name___26P8X"><a href="/player/riccardo-orsolini">R.Orsolini</a><a class="Row__team___3CPAz" href="/club/Bologna">Bologna</a></div></div><div class="Change__container___ZKCNS Change__container__positive___2mmVZ">£0.03</div><div class="BuyAndSellButtons__buttonContainer___3uLe5"><button class="Button__sell-background___Pu5NC Button__button___3_Ozh Button__tradingMedium___TOIwW Button__yellow-glow___20bvG SellButton__price___3omkd tradingMedium SellButton__default___2LgzG" id="sell" type="button">£1.83</button><button class="Button__buy-background___3wyrT Button__button___3_Ozh Button__tradingMedium___TOIwW Button__yellow-glow___20bvG BuyButton__price___1Ylr9 tradingMedium" id="buy" type="button">£2.00</button></div></div><div class="sc-bwzfXH gXUZUa"><div class="Pic__container___3KX2N Pic__container__threeColumns___1Zbax"><div class="Pic__container__rank___3rCJC">181</div><div class="Pic__hexagonContainer___3tlAo"><div class="HexagonContainer__hexagon___3lz4M Pic__container__celebImage___LfP-u"><div class="HexagonContainer__innerHexagon___DbA3c"><div class="HexagonContainer__coreHexagon___3HXiI"><img alt="Leon Goretzka" class="HexagonImage__imageContents___ZSIfo HexagonImage__image___2jE99" src="https://img.footballindex.co.uk/leon-goretzka-g-t6.jpg"/></div></div></div></div><div class="Pic__container__name___26P8X"><a href="/player/leon-goretzka">L.Goretzka</a><a class="Row__team___3CPAz" href="/club/FC_Bayern_München">FC Bayern München</a></div></div><div class="Change__container___ZKCNS Change__container__positive___2mmVZ">£0.03</div><div class="BuyAndSellButtons__buttonContainer___3uLe5"><button class="Button__sell-background___Pu5NC Button__button___3_Ozh Button__tradingMedium___TOIwW Button__yellow-glow___20bvG SellButton__price___3omkd tradingMedium SellButton__default___2LgzG" id="sell" type="button">£1.64</button><button class="Button__buy-background___3wyrT Button__button___3_Ozh Button__tradingMedium___TOIwW Button__yellow-glow___20bvG BuyButton__price___1Ylr9 tradingMedium" id="buy" type="button">£1.73</button></div></div><div class="sc-bwzfXH gXUZUa"><div class="Pic__container___3KX2N Pic__container__threeColumns___1Zbax"><div class="Pic__container__rank___3rCJC">17</div><div class="Pic__hexagonContainer___3tlAo"><div class="HexagonContainer__hexagon___3lz4M Pic__container__celebImage___LfP-u"><div class="HexagonContainer__innerHexagon___DbA3c"><div class="HexagonContainer__coreHexagon___3HXiI"><img alt="Ansu Fati" class="HexagonImage__imageContents___ZSIfo HexagonImage__image___2jE99" src="https://img.footballindex.co.uk/ansu-fati-g-t2.jpg"/></div></div></div></div><div class="Pic__container__name___26P8X"><a href="/player/ansu-fati">A.Fati</a><a class="Row__team___3CPAz" href="/club/Barcelona">Barcelona</a></div></div><div class="Change__container___ZKCNS Change__container__positive___2mmVZ">£0.02</div><div class="BuyAndSellButtons__buttonContainer___3uLe5"><button class="Button__sell-background___Pu5NC Button__button___3_Ozh Button__tradingMedium___TOIwW Button__yellow-glow___20bvG SellButton__price___3omkd tradingMedium SellButton__default___2LgzG" id="sell" type="button">£4.66</button><button class="Button__buy-background___3wyrT Button__button___3_Ozh Button__tradingMedium___TOIwW Button__yellow-glow___20bvG BuyButton__price___1Ylr9 tradingMedium" id="buy" type="button">£4.88</button></div></div><div class="sc-bwzfXH gXUZUa"><div class="Pic__container___3KX2N Pic__container__threeColumns___1Zbax"><div class="Pic__container__rank___3rCJC">25</div><div class="Pic__hexagonContainer___3tlAo"><div class="HexagonContainer__hexagon___3lz4M Pic__container__celebImage___LfP-u"><div class="HexagonContainer__innerHexagon___DbA3c"><div class="HexagonContainer__coreHexagon___3HXiI"><img alt="Alphonso Davies" class="HexagonImage__imageContents___ZSIfo HexagonImage__image___2jE99" src="https://img.footballindex.co.uk/alphonso-davies-g-t2.jpg"/></div></div></div></div><div class="Pic__container__name___26P8X"><a href="/player/alphonso-davies">A.Davies</a><a class="Row__team___3CPAz" href="/club/FC_Bayern_München">FC Bayern München</a></div></div><div class="Change__container___ZKCNS Change__container__positive___2mmVZ">£0.02</div><div class="BuyAndSellButtons__buttonContainer___3uLe5"><button class="Button__sell-background___Pu5NC Button__button___3_Ozh Button__tradingMedium___TOIwW Button__yellow-glow___20bvG SellButton__price___3omkd tradingMedium SellButton__default___2LgzG" id="sell" type="button">£4.02</button><button class="Button__buy-background___3wyrT Button__button___3_Ozh Button__tradingMedium___TOIwW Button__yellow-glow___20bvG BuyButton__price___1Ylr9 tradingMedium" id="buy" type="button">£4.32</button></div></div><div class="sc-bwzfXH gXUZUa"><div class="Pic__container___3KX2N Pic__container__threeColumns___1Zbax"><div class="Pic__container__rank___3rCJC">119</div><div class="Pic__hexagonContainer___3tlAo"><div class="HexagonContainer__hexagon___3lz4M Pic__container__celebImage___LfP-u"><div class="HexagonContainer__innerHexagon___DbA3c"><div class="HexagonContainer__coreHexagon___3HXiI"><img alt="Adil Aouchiche" class="HexagonImage__imageContents___ZSIfo HexagonImage__image___2jE99" src="https://img.footballindex.co.uk/adil-aouchiche-g-t1.jpg"/></div></div></div></div><div class="Pic__container__name___26P8X"><a href="/player/adil-aouchiche">A.Aouchiche</a><a class="Row__team___3CPAz" href="/club/Paris_Saint-Germain">Paris Saint-Germain</a></div></div><div class="Change__container___ZKCNS Change__container__positive___2mmVZ">£0.02</div><div class="BuyAndSellButtons__buttonContainer___3uLe5"><button class="Button__sell-background___Pu5NC Button__button___3_Ozh Button__tradingMedium___TOIwW Button__yellow-glow___20bvG SellButton__price___3omkd tradingMedium SellButton__default___2LgzG" id="sell" type="button">£1.92</button><button class="Button__buy-background___3wyrT Button__button___3_Ozh Button__tradingMedium___TOIwW Button__yellow-glow___20bvG BuyButton__price___1Ylr9 tradingMedium" id="buy" type="button">£2.13</button></div></div><div class="sc-bwzfXH gXUZUa"><div class="Pic__container___3KX2N Pic__container__threeColumns___1Zbax"><div class="Pic__container__rank___3rCJC">129</div><div class="Pic__hexagonContainer___3tlAo"><div class="HexagonContainer__hexagon___3lz4M Pic__container__celebImage___LfP-u"><div class="HexagonContainer__innerHexagon___DbA3c"><div class="HexagonContainer__coreHexagon___3HXiI"><img alt="Brandon Williams" class="HexagonImage__imageContents___ZSIfo HexagonImage__image___2jE99" src="https://img.footballindex.co.uk/brandon-williams-g-t2.jpg"/></div></div></div></div><div class="Pic__container__name___26P8X"><a href="/player/brandon-williams">B.Williams</a><a class="Row__team___3CPAz" href="/club/Manchester_United">Manchester United</a></div></div><div class="Change__container___ZKCNS Change__container__positive___2mmVZ">£0.02</div><div class="BuyAndSellButtons__buttonContainer___3uLe5"><button class="Button__sell-background___Pu5NC Button__button___3_Ozh Button__tradingMedium___TOIwW Button__yellow-glow___20bvG SellButton__price___3omkd tradingMedium SellButton__default___2LgzG" id="sell" type="button">£1.97</button><button class="Button__buy-background___3wyrT Button__button___3_Ozh Button__tradingMedium___TOIwW Button__yellow-glow___20bvG BuyButton__price___1Ylr9 tradingMedium" id="buy" type="button">£2.08</button></div></div><div class="sc-bwzfXH gXUZUa"><div class="Pic__container___3KX2N Pic__container__threeColumns___1Zbax"><div class="Pic__container__rank___3rCJC">5</div><div class="Pic__hexagonContainer___3tlAo"><div   </div>
```

Here is a result of regex - list with all Buy prices.

```
[('buy" type="button">', '£8.08', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£6.33', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£10.36', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£2.09', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£2.08', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£2.00', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£2.26', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£1.73', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£6.09', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£4.88', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£4.32', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£2.13', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£2.08', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£5.16', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£4.03', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£3.48', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£3.35', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£3.31', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£3.18', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£3.14', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£2.95', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£2.90', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£2.85', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£2.81', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£2.79', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£2.79', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£2.75', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£2.63', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£2.62', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£2.56', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£2.55', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£2.53', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£2.50', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£2.47', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£2.43', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£2.38', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£2.37', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£2.36', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£2.30', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£2.28', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£2.25', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£2.21', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£2.20', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£2.19', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£2.17', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£2.09', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£2.08', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£2.04', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£2.02', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£2.02', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£2.01', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£1.90', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£1.86', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£1.85', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£1.84', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£1.81', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£1.80', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£1.80', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£1.79', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£1.77', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£1.75', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£1.74', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£1.73', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£1.70', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£1.69', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£1.69', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£1.68', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£1.66', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£1.64', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£1.64', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£1.64', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£1.63', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£6.05', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£4.40', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£4.01', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£3.67', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£3.49', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£2.96', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£2.69', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£2.58', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£2.39', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£2.31', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£2.26', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£2.20', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£2.19', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£2.11', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£2.09', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£2.08', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£2.05', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£2.01', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£1.99', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£1.99', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£1.95', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£1.89', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£1.89', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£1.85', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£1.83', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£1.82', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£1.69', '</button>'), ('buy" type="button">', '£1.68', '</button>')]
```

I recommmend https://pythex.org/ where you can test your regex without having to run script every time.

Comment: If you found it usefull please mark it as Answered. It will boot my profile as I'm very new on stackoverflow.

Comment: Omg thank you so much, I used a different approach to store the data once I'd used your method to get the true page html but you're a life saver!! THANK YOU!